# jquery returns only one attribute of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

**EDIT: this code is working in JSFIDDLE and in my other pages**.

I have this url:

```
<a title="Modifica descrizione '.$row['nome'].'" class="toEdit" href="edit_gruppo.php?id='.$row['id'].'">
```

in the browser it is rendered as:

```
<a class="toEdit" href="edit_gruppo.php?id=2" title="Modifica descrizione gruppo2">
<img alt="modifica" src="images/edit.jpg">
</a>
```

and using Jquery I do:

```
$('.toEdit').click(function(e) {
    var titolo = $(this).attr('title');
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(titolo);
    console.log(url);
    $('#modaler').load(url).dialog({title: titolo}).dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

The above code returns url but not title. I cannot see what is wrong here. Can anyone advice?

Comment: 'title' is not a recognized attribute for the anchor tag. Use either 'name' or 'data-title'.

Comment: I use it in many other different scripts and it use to work fine. Anyway I'll try this workaround. Thanks

Comment: Works for me/.....http://jsfiddle.net/STN9j/152/

Comment: I see. For me console.log returns "empty string" while url is returned.

Comment: Then it must be something in the rest of my code.... thanks for the help

Comment: "Title is not recognized for anchor tag" where you got that ?

Comment: What is Wrong with This fiddle ? http://jsfiddle.net/b3Lyzwr2/2/

Comment: Nothing. But when I place it inside the whole page it doesn't work only for the "title" part. Renamed "title" to "name" and it works as expected and as your fiddle does

Comment: What's the HTML in brower? You posted a piece of PHP, that nobody knows whether it is wrong on server side or client.

Comment: @Sidd `title` is a [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title)

Comment: The html is correct. Just for your info I am editing my code with what you see in the browser.

Comment: Make a fiddle that can reproduce your problem, otherwise I'm afraid you won't get anything.

Comment: I remember trying to use the title tag on anchor tag and running into problems. Might be just a browser-specific thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to close `</a>` tag -
[see result](https://jsfiddle.net/dimitrioglo/qdd75ygx/2/)

Comment: The <a> tag is closed. I just posted the relevant part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by changing the title attribute with name. 
Issue is related to tooltip plugin. When the user hover the link it removes the title from the link and shows it in a tooltip. So, when the link is clicked actually it has no title specified.